# Laravel define relationship between two tables

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have the following tables

```
1. Environment
--------------
env_id
env_name
env_description
repo_id

2. Repository
--------------
repo_id
repo_name
repo_url
```

Now multiple environments can be associated with same repository. I am very new to Eloquent and so has a confusion that which kind of relation this is ? I have an api and I would like to return repo details when I access an environment endoint. So when I use `Evironment::all()`, I would like to get the associated Repository. How can I do this ?

I went through the examples given in the documentation, but it seems like I have a scenario which is not mentioned there.

Comment: `Repository` hasMany `Environment` or `Environment` hasMany `Repository`?

Comment: no your scenario is exactly a hasMany relationship that is described in the documentation ... you are just missing the loading of the relationship side

Comment: So I think I need to add the relationship `repository()` in `Environment` model with `hasMany`

Comment: its the inverse ......  Environment belongs to Repository (because repository key is on environment)  ; Repository hasMany Environment

Comment: In that case , how can I access the related repositories when using `Environment::all()` . Sorry for being a pain.

Answer (score 0):

That will be a One To Many(inverse) relationship.

```
//Environment Model
public function repository()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Repository');
}

//Repository Model
public function environments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Environment', 'repo_id');
}
```

Then you can return all the Environment with their relationship as follow:

```
Environment::with('repository')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it should be a one-to-many relationship between two tables. Therefore, in plain English sentences, it would be, the `Repository` has many `Environment`s and the `Environment` model belongs to the `Repository`. Let's build up those two models.

Repository model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Repository extends Model
{
    public function environments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Environment::class);
    }
}
```

Environment model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Environment extends Model
{
    public function repo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Repository::class);
    }
}
```

**Notice**: I name after `Environment::repo()` instead of `Environment::repository()`.

If we called `Environment::repository` as a property on the `Environment` object inside a foreach loop, it would return `null` instead of `Repository` object. It may be eloquent's naming issue. To be honest, I don't know the reason so far. I'm using Laravel 7.

Once you're done with the creations of models, you can play with data using them. As you need to get the associated `Repository` object with `Environment` object, check out the following code:

```
<?php

$environments = Environment::all();

foreach ($environments as $environment) {
    echo $environment->repo->repo_name . '<br>';
}
```